# Can I use JOIN instead of a subquery to get COUNT() across tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have one table that stores posts. Each post object has a postTypeId that denotes if it's a question post or an answer post. I would like to get question posts and count the number of answer posts each question post has. Can I do this using a JOIN instead of a subquery as shown below? The schema assumes the following: `postsTable(id, postTypeId, parentId, title)`

```
SELECT
    posts.id, posts.postTypeId, posts.parentId, posts.title
    , (SELECT COUNT(answers.id) AS answerCount FROM posts AS answers WHERE posts.id = answers.parentId GROUP BY posts.postTypeId)
    FROM posts
    WHERE posts.postTypeId = '1'
```

Also, is the GROUP By necessary in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
        p.id, count(answers.id) answerCount, p.title
FROM posts p
     LEFT JOIN posts answers 
    ON posts.id = answers.parentId
WHERE
    p.postTypeId = '1'
GROUP BY
 
p.id, p.title
```

Take a look at [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16124/) to see it for SO

The main advantages to this is that its typically faster and more readable but it also allows you to get more data from "Answers".

E.g.

```
SELECT
        p.id, count(answers.id) answerCount, p.title, MAX(Answers.Score) HighScore, 
FROM posts p
     LEFT JOIN posts answers 
    ON posts.id = answers.parentId
WHERE
    p.postTypeId = '1'
GROUP BY

p.id, p.title
```

Comment: Thanks Conrad, that's awesome! Are there any relative advantages/disadvantages to each approach?

Comment: Conrad, again, thats fantastic. One final thing: Suppose you wanted to join votes on that query, you would add an additional join as such: left join votes on p.id = votes.postid; I just tried this, but the sums are all incorrect! It seems as though the "votes" count is count the votes for the parent post and the children ones... does this make sense?

Comment: What I meant to say was, adding an additional COUNT(votes.id) messes up the original count. I think the query counts votes.id for every iteration of count(answers.id)... I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Do you want the vote count per answer or the sum of the vote count per answer

Comment: Conrad: I really only want the voteCount per question! So basically: Say 2 questions, the answer count for each question, and the vote count for each question.. I'm not looking for any data on the answers!

Comment: That gets a little bet more complicated. As you noted the answer count would = the vote count. You'll need to a subquery in either the select or the from .  see http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16129/mels-questions-with-answers-and-votes

Comment: Conrad, wow! Many thanks, this was an eye opened! It is very complicated! Doesn't seem like it's worth it either! I can see why the SO schema is denormalized!

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT posts.id, posts.postTypeId, posts.parentId, posts.title, COUNT(answers.id) AS answerCount 
    FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = answers.parentId
    WHERE posts.postTypeId = '1'
    GROUP BY posts.id
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT questions.id, questions.posttypeID, questions.parentID, questions.title, count(questions.id) AS NUM_OF_ANSWERS
FROM posts AS questions
LEFT JOIN posts AS answers on (answers.parentID = questions.id)
WHERE questions.postTypeID = '1';
ORDER BY questions.id, questions.posttypeID, questions.parentID, questions.title;
```

Comment: Looks like Conrad beat me to it. Make sure you include all columns you list in the SELECT clause in the order by clause, excluding the count()

Comment: Thanks suhprano! There is one additional thing that I can't seem to fingur out. Let's say I wanted to join votes and get a votes count on the question... this appears to mess up the answer acount, and I'm not sure why... I'm simply duplicating the join for answers!

Comment: So there's a question, with answers associated, along with votes associated with the question?

Comment: @mel This self left join with the order by is what results for the count of answers. If votes is logged in a different table, you might want to just do a subquery for that particular post id.

select ... count (questions.id) , 
(select count(vote.id) from vote join posts on (vote.postid= posts.id) 
from posts AS questions
LEFT Join posts AS answers ...

Not sure if that'll work, but something along those lines...